# Install a GCC ARM Embedded toolchain

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, toolchain

I would like to load a very simple, hello world program, on an Embedded ARM processor. For this, I would like to install a toolchain in order to cross compile my code. I am currently working on a 64-bit Linux OS. Does anyone know of a GCC ARM embedded toolchain that I can download? I've downloaded a pre-built version of Linaro GCC but it only runs on a 32-bit Linux machine and I can't install the ia32-libs package because my Linux machine has no internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

The gcc-arm toolchain I'm using for ARM Cortex-M processors can be found here-
https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

It also builds for Cortex-A targets, which should cover the majority of embedded ARM systems.

You can download standalone distributions for many operating systems, including linux.

Comment: Question, 4 Years later - Is this still current (i.e. the standard way to do this)? And does the toolchain support ARM NEON (arm_neon.h) ... I would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

There are also 64bit builds of Linaro toolchain [here](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/7.2-2017.11/arm-linux-gnueabi/). Just download the x86_64 and not the i686 version.